# Is there a way to do model inference using GPU with Python code on mobile?

Tags: python, android, mobile, vulkan

I want to run the model inference code that runs on a computer GPU written in Python code on a mobile device, but I am blocked by several problems. Actually, there would be no problem if this code was converted to Java code, but it would take too much time.

First of all, I use the pydroid3 app, but the Python version cannot be changed within the app, so the desired package version cannot be downloaded.
Next, I try to download the vulkan SDK on pydroid3, but the git command does not work, and even if I try to put the file directly in the sdk_root path, it is impossible because of permission denied.
Does anyone have this experience? I would like to ask for help from someone who is familiar with pydroid3.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.